# Lwuit 1.5 GUI Builder generate cod files

Tags: lwuit, gui-builder

Can anyone tell me how to sign and get the cod files using lwuit1.5 resource editor after you finish a Blackberry project using GUI BUILDER.

Note: I am using only the Lwuit1.5 not the CodenameOne .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to sign the cod files with the Resource Editor. I don't think that this is possible. I generate my cod files from the Netbeans. When I ran a BB project, it compiles and generate the cod and the alx files. For using the BB plugin and BB emulators in Netbeans http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/11194/rim-blackberry-plugin

Comment: Finally I found out the way myself to sign App and create the cod files after creating a project using gui builder .

Comment: You need to do some chance in xml file if want i can mail u the detail procedure on how to do give me your mail id